# Docker: How to install memcached in container

Tags: caching, docker, memcached, codeigniter-3, docker-container

I am using php:5.6-apache docker image for local development. Now I am developing one portal using codeigniter3. I want to use memcached for caching purpose. But it was not found by default in php:5.6-apache image.

How can i install memcached in my container?

Right now I am trying to use memcached container for this purpose but don't get success yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like this:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build: .
  memcached:
    image: memcached
```

You can point to memcached container from php container as this: `memcached:11211`

You will need to enable php-memcached mod in your current php Dockerfile.